# rake 0.9.2 isn't recognized in bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundle, mysql2

This is the error I get when I run db:migrate.

`rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.`

I then run bundle exec rake 0.9.2 and this is what I get

```
    'rake aborted!dlopen(/Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2 0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib Referenced from: /Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the correct MYSQL2 gem.  In you Gemfile, make sure you included mysql2

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Then rebundle and try

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I tried running that and got rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/connorphillips/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Comment: Do you have the mysql libraries installed locally?  Can you do "gem install mysql2" Based on the error messages, it appears that the binary files that the gem relies on are not being found.